# Essential matrix in epipolar geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computational-geometry

According to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029593/epipolar-geometry-essential-matrix-derivation-question),the correct result is `Pr=R(Pl-T)`.`R,T` is the transformation from `Caml` to `Camr`.`Pl` is the position in `Caml`'s camera coordinate system.`Pr` is the position in `Camr`'s camera coordinate system.

In my opinion,if we know the transformation between two coordinate system,then it should be `Pr=R*Pl+T`.

I wonder to know where i was wrong.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you’re getting the order of transformations backwards. In the left-hand camera’s coordinate system, the displacement vector $\mathbf T$ is just the coordinates of the right-hand camera center. To transform a point’s coordinates into the right-hand camera’s frame, you must *first* translate the origin to $\mathbf T$, *then* rotate: $\mathbf P_r = \mathtt R \left(\mathbf P_l-\mathbf T \right)$. You could rotate first, of course, but then the subsequent translation must be performed in this new rotated coordinate system, i.e., the displacement vector $\mathbf T$ must also be rotated. Algebraically, $\mathtt R \left(\mathbf P_l-\mathbf T \right) = \mathtt R \mathbf P_l-\mathtt R\mathbf T$.

I suspect that you may have been misled by the typical decomposition $\mathtt K \left[ \mathtt R \mid \mathbf t \right]$ of the camera projection matrix. In this decomposition, $\mathbf t$ is not the camera center $\tilde{\mathbf C}$ in world coordinates, but is in fact equal to $-\mathtt R \tilde{\mathbf C}$.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer!It's means that in the typical camera projection model,the transformation is `Pc=Rcw*[Pw-(-Rwc*t)]=Rcw*Pw+t`.But i don't think that there is a left-hand coordinate system to right-hand coordinate system.Like stereo camera,the two camera's coordinate system is same(both left-hand or right-hand).

Comment: @zdczdcc In your question, you wrote that the transformation was “from `Caml` to `Camr`, but you left unspecified how either of the camera matrices relate to world coordinates. It sounds like you’re assuming a standard camera $\mathtt K[\mathtt I\mid\mathbf 0]$ for `Caml`, which is not necessary for the construction that you’re asking about.

Comment: Sorry for the unspecified question description.And thanks for your help!

Comment: I got in trouble again.Now i think the camera model is `Pc=Rcw*[Pw-(-Rwc*t)]=Rcw*Pw+t`.Since i know the camera center in world coordinate is `-Rwc*t`.But the calculation of `-Rwc*t` is based on the equation `Pc=Rcw*Pw+t`.That is said,i'v used the final result during the derivation.And how to get the camera center in world coordinate system.

Comment: Now i think the **T** is only relative position of `Caml`'s center in `Camr`'s coordinate system and not the translation vector from `Caml`'s coordinate system to `Camr`'s coordinate system.In this situation ,we get `Pr=R(Pl-T)`.If we get the translation vector from `Caml`'s coordinate system to `Camr`'s coordinate system,mark as **t**,we would get `Pr=R*Pl+t`.Am i wrong?Please give me some advice.Thanks!

Comment: @zdczdcc It seems like you’re just guessing based on the one slide in the other question. I strongly suggest that you try to find the full lecture notes or use other similar sources, such as [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4a28/fa13b4b4e203334209fb7b386171871b78eb.pdf). The bottom line is that $R(P_l-T)$ is quite simply the coordinate transformation from the left-hand camera coordinate system to the right. Getting the correct expression for it is a matter of applying the two transformations in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!I got the above conclusion based on the book `Multi View Geometry in Computer Vision,2nd Edition`.I agree that the bottom line is `R(Pl-T)`,and it is the transformation from the left-hand camera coordinate system to the right.In that book,the translation vector `t=-RC`,so the equation can be described as `Pr=R*Pl+t`.Then i think,the `T` in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029593/epipolar-geometry-essential-matrix-derivation-question),might not be the translation vector from `Caml` to `Camr`.It just a vector in `Caml`'s coordinate system.

Comment: @zdczdcc Order matters. $\mathbf t$ is a translation applied after rotation; $\mathbf T$ here is applied before.

Comment: I get it now and thanks a lot for your answer!